# Warning: implicit declaration of function 'toupper'

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
     char l,u;
     printf("Enter any lowercase number: ");
     scanf(" %c",&l);
     u = toupper(l);
     printf("The uppercase number is: %c\n",u);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Include the header <ctype.h>

Comment: `#include <ctype.h>`

Answer (score 1):

The `toupper()` function is declared in the `<ctype.h>` header file. So you have to include that at the top.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main() {
     char l,u;
     printf("Enter any lowercase number: ");
     scanf(" %c",&l);
     u = toupper(l);
     printf("The uppercase number is: %c\n",u);
     return 0;
}
```